# MailApp.sendEmail() not sending from current user

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an onEdit triggered appscript that grabs data from a spreadsheet, formats it and then sends it to an email address. Typically these messages would be sent 'from' the user that is triggering the script to run. However, I am experiencing strange behavior where the current user is not used to send the message - or used inconsistently.

A couple of notes:

- Occasionally the message *is* sent by the current user, other times it is not (in those cases it comes from my account, which created the script)
- Script trigger is an 'onEdit' script which monitors the sheet for a checkbox status change
- Spreadsheet is in a Shared Drive
- We are using Google apps for education
- The recipient address is a mailing list tool. When I list a different email address as the recipient (internal, external, other) the message consistently comes from the current user as expected. I've no idea why the recipient would affect how Google sends the message.

I realize i could use the GmailApp library to send instead, but want to avoid the re-authorizations that are mentioned.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) Please Provide code

Comment: see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions > Installable triggers always run under the account of the person who created them. For example, if you create an installable open trigger, it runs when your colleague opens the document (if your colleague has edit access), but it runs as your account. This means that if you create a trigger to send an email when a document is opened, the email is always sent from your account, not necessarily the account that opened the document.

Comment: > However, you could create an installable trigger for each account, which would result in one email sent from each account.